# Is this property assignment for iOS correct?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've seen that you should assign a property this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    self.dateFormatter = tempFormatter;
    [tempFormatter release];
}

...

- (void)dealloc {

    [dateFomatter release];
    [super relase];
}
```

Where dateFormatter is defined like this

```
// Header
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

// Implementation
@synthesize dateFomatter;
```

This way I avoid a double assignment.

Comment: Uhm.. What exactly is that 180°-turned question mark ("¿") doing there?

Comment: My guess is the OP is spanish, since you'd write: *¿Como estas?*, for instance, to ask how you're doing, it's part of the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is ok. It uses the `retain` from the synthesized setter.